# Access: Print selected records form query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I really don't know how to start this. I have a report, that takes records from a query. The query itself takes the records from a table. Now I want to be able to select the records in the query by the id manually. But there is no connection between the records, so I can't say 'give me all records between id x and y'. Also, there is not the count of records always changing. I want a user to be able to say: 'okay, I need to print all the data of these x ids'. how can I archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the object using Querydef and used this to change your query at runtime based on the user slected criteria.

try like this

```
Dim query_1 as string

query_1 = "Select * from Table1 where ID  = 'Your ID'"

CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Report_Query").sql = query_1
```

than open the report or make pdf ..

Comment: That won't give the ability to print different selections of records though? Only one record.

Comment: @Minty may be he had some id which is not a primary key.

Comment: That's possible, but you can still use an IN( ) clause even if it's a text field, and not unique.

Answer (score 1):

You could populate a multiselect listbox from the same record source as the report, and then use the selected records from that to drive the actual report data.

You would probably want to build a `PK IN(1,3,99,104...)`  style criteria by looping through the selected items from the listbox.