# Microsoft Access sql juggling

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys, relationship, user-input

The end-user chooses something from a drop-down (it shows description text related to unique ID, but doesn't show the ID)

How would I go about making a further query that uses the user input ID as a parameter for further manipulation?

```
select x,y 
from table1 
where k in {1,2,23}
```

Let's say the user selects 23

```
select j,l
from table2
where k=23 and {other conditions}
```

Comment: check this out  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913360/access-print-selected-records-form-query/50922960#50922960)

Comment: *The end-user chooses something from a drop-down*. Is that control on a form? or it is directly on table/query?

Comment: I want to ease myself the trouble for entry of 1000 items, but the main goal, yes, is to have the control on a form

Comment: Search for *access cascading combobox* (at least I think this is what you are looking for).

Comment: then, something like `where k=" & combobox.value` should work.

Comment: thanks for the tip @Andre that actually solved half of the question.

The other half remains

Can this be done WITHOUT forms, where one table.column.value is used as the condition or not?
I possibly blew this out of proportion, but it will be a useful time-saver for any successive projects with Access...

Comment: Cascading combobox requires code to requery combobox. Cannot be done in table or query. But if you do not want cascading combobox, but progressive filtering of table or query, also not pracitcal with VBA.

Comment: Alright so the answer to my question is:

I can't have what I want without forms, and when I accept having to have forms, the solution is called

Cascading combobox


Thanks for all your support, people!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Search for access cascading combobox (at least I think this is what you are looking for). – Andre 20 hours ago
>
> thanks for the tip @Andre that actually solved half of the question. The other half remains Can this be done WITHOUT forms, where one table.column.value is used as the condition or not? I possibly blew this out of proportion, but it will be a useful time-saver for any successive projects with Access... – Nikola Pavlovic
>
> Cascading combobox requires code to requery combobox. Cannot be done in table or query. But if you do not want cascading combobox, but progressive filtering of table or query, also not pracitcal with VBA. – June7 11 hours ago
>
> Alright so the answer to my question is: I can't have what I want without forms, and when I accept having to have forms, the solution is called Cascading combobox Thanks for all your support, people!!! – Nikola Pavlovic 39 mins ago

The issue is resolved. Thanks again to everyone!!!